# REST Web Service | Drupal or Symfony

Tags: rest, symfony, drupal

An application which is developed by Symfony 2 should retrieve data through a REST Web Service from a web site which is developed by Drupal.

How should the REST web service be developed?

Comment: A good starting point could be: http://symfony.com/doc/current/bundles/FOSRestBundle/index.html - but your question is by far too broad.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, so if I understand correctly you have two services:

1. Symfony2 app - requires data
2. Drupal app - has data

So you need to develop an API for Drupal which will be accessed by the Symfony2 app.

Now, I should tell you, this is a very beginer question. So you should start at the beginning.
Research the following topics:
"What is an API"
"What is a REST service"
"How to get data from an API with PHP"

then you need basics of Drupal module development and more specifically Drupal API module development. You'll need to know the version od Drupal as 7 and 8 differ quite a bit.

Answer (score 0):

Building REST service with Drupal is documented https://www.drupal.org/documentation/modules/rest. Basically, you expose Drupal internal data models (called entities) through a REST API using JSON as format. On the Drupal side there is no code to write, everything should be configurable from the UI. When using Drupal 8, the configuration is exportable using the built-in Configuration Management. With Drupal 7, you should be able to export the configuration as code using the Features module.